# When using password_verify, any password suffices, why?

Tags: php, passwords, verify

have read all the questions I could find related to this and still can't find a helpful answer (helpful to me that is).

My problem is that I can log in with any password when using password_verify.

login_process.php

```
include_once("db.php"); 

if(!empty($_POST['login'])) { 
        // Escape variables
        $input_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectdb, $_POST['username']);
        $input_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectdb, $_POST['password']);

//Query to find username
            $query = "SELECT id, username, password, email FROM usersdt091g WHERE username = '$input_username'";
            $query2 = "SELECT password FROM usersdt091g WHERE username = '$input_username'";
            $res = mysqli_query($connectdb, $query2);
            $dbpass = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            $hash = $dbpass[0]['password'];
            $result = mysqli_query($connectdb, $query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        // Login ok = false, then render it true if conditions met
        $login_ok = false; 

        if(password_verify($input_password, $hash)) 
        { 
                // If they do, then we flip this to true 
                $login_ok = true; 
        } 

        // If login ok
        if($login_ok = true) 
        {
            // Session variables
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row;

            // Redirect user to secret page. 
            header('Location: blahalblal'); 
            exit; 
        } else {
            // Tell the user they failed
            $errors[] = "<p>Login Failed MISERABLY!</p>"; 
        }
    }
?>
```

[Image of Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOjhS.png)

My registration process looks like this.
signup.php

```
<?php 
   include_once("db.php"); 

    if(isset($_POST['signup']))
{
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectdb, $_POST['username']);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectdb, $_POST['email']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectdb, $_POST['password']);
 $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

 if(mysqli_query($connectdb, "INSERT INTO usersdt091g (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username','$email','$hash')"))
 { 
     $successs[] = "<p>Great Success, please login!</p>";
 }
}
?>
```

I could use all and any assistance,

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will *always* be true:

```
if($login_ok = true)
```

Because the result of assigning a boolean value is the boolean value itself.  You probably meant to *compare* the value instead of *assign* it:

```
if($login_ok == true)
```

Comment: Aww, maan! Thanks David! However, now I can't login....what am I doing wrong when comparing stored hash password, with submitted hash password?

Comment: @StudentEric: Not sure.  The use of `password_verify()` looks correct.  Can you debug this and find out the exact values being compared?  Is there some way to manually hash the password in PHP to see if it really does match?  Also, why are you querying the same database table twice?

Comment: I am querying twice for no reason other than adding the session  later than adding the password check. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found works, thanks to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) I got the whole comparison operator out of the way. I also removed the unnecessary query. In order to get both username and user password from the database to match input I had to make sure they matched. Stare myself blind sometimes but yeah, match both username and user password before `$login_ok == true`.

```
<?php 
   include_once("db.php"); 

if(!empty($_POST['login'])) { 
        // Escape variables
        $input_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectdb, $_POST['username']);
        $input_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectdb, $_POST['password']);
        //Query to find username
        $query = "SELECT id, username, password, email FROM users WHERE username = '$input_username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connectdb, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $userid = $row['username'];
        $hash = $row['password'];
        //var_dump($dbpassword[0]);
        // Login ok = false, then render it true if conditions met
        $login_ok = false; 

        if(password_verify($input_password, $hash) && $userid === $input_username) 
        { 
                // If they do, then we flip this to true 
                $login_ok = true; 
        } 

        // If login ok
        if($login_ok == true) 
        {
            // Session variables
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row;

            // Redirect user to secret page. 
            header('Location: portfolio_admin.php'); 
            exit; 
        } else {
            // Tell the user they failed
            $errors[] = "<p>Login Failed MISERABLY!</p>"; 
        }
    }
?>
```